# Conventions for Relief (depth) Python for desktop applications

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I can't find any advice on what is the correct way to use relief. When to use *sunken*, *raised*, *flat*, *groove* and *ridge* (terminology of [tkinter](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_relief.htm)) in a GUI application? Rather than purely visual, I suppose they are there to deliver a(n implicit) message to the user.

I use Python 3.3 and use the formulation of tkinter, but I guess the principles apply to any desktop application. I am sure people gave this a lot of thought.

What are the guidelines/conventions for relief?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no official guidelines, or at least, no general purpose guidelines. The best advice I can offer is "use whatever the other applications in your target platform use". This changes over time.

Back in the 80's and 90's this typically meant a two-pixel raised border for buttons and frames, which gave a somewhat "chunky" look to everything. In the 2000's things became a bit more streamlined and borders shrunk to one pixel. Now, the rage seems to be for more flat GUIs.

Comment: Apparently I expected it to be more objective than it is. Thank you.

Comment: @Dualinity: I should have mentioned that each platform may have specific guidelines for a particular version of the OS